# Verificar se é vogal ou consoante e se é minúscula ou maiúscula sem usar funções prontas

Tags: c, string

Estou desenvolvendo duas funções em linguagem C, a primeira para verificar se uma letra é uma vogal ou uma consoante, sem usar nenhuma função pronta. A primeira está funcionando.

A segunda função verifica se a letra é maiúscula ou minúscula, mas não funciona para todas as letras. Por exemplo, a letra "a" não apresenta resultado.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char letras[52] = {'A','E', 'I','O','U',
                    'a','e', 'i','o','u',
                    'B','C','D','F','G','H','J','K','L','M','N','P','Q','R','S','T','V','W','X','Y','Z',
                    'b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','v','w','x','y','z'
};

void minusculaMaiuscula(char letra){
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++){
        if( (i < 5 | (i > 10 & i < 31)) & (letra == letras[i]) ){
            printf("Maiuscula");
            break;
        }
        else if ( (i > 5 & i < 31) & letra == letras[i] ){
            printf("Minuscula");
            break;
        }
    }        
}

void vogalConsoante(char letra){
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++){
        if(i < 10 & letra == letras[i] ){
            printf("Vogal");
            break;
        }
        else if (i > 5 & letra == letras[i] ){
            printf("Consoante");
            break;
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    char letra = 'a';
    minusculaMaiuscula(letra);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Onde está o erro na minha função `minusculaMaiuscula(char letra)` e, como melhorá estas funções de modo que o codigo seja mais compreensivel e com menos instruções?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Na verdade não precisa desse array de letras, bastaria verificar se o `char` está entre as letras "a" e "z":

```
void minusculaMaiuscula(char letra) {
    if ('a' <= letra && letra <= 'z') {
        printf("Minúscula\n");
    } else if ('A' <= letra && letra <= 'Z') {
        printf("Maiúscula\n");
    } else {
        printf("Não é letra\n");
    }
}
```

Se quiser que não imprima nada caso não seja uma letra, basta retirar o último `else`.

---

Se quiser mesmo usar o array, o problema do seu código é que faltou testar o caso em que `i` é igual a 5 (você testa se é menor ou se é maior, mas quando for igual, não entra em nenhuma das condições). Não avaliei as demais condições, mas na verdade dá para simplificá-las, como veremos abaixo.

Você também pode mudar os operadores `|` e `&`, que na verdade são [operadores *bitwise*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic). Em vez disso, pode usar os [operadores lógicos](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical) "or" e "and" (que são respectivamente `||` e `&&`).

A vantagem de usar `&&` e `||` é que eles possuem a característica de serem [*short-circuit*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45848858) e só avaliam todas as condições caso seja necessário (por exemplo, `a && b` só é verdadeiro se ambas as condições `a` e `b` também forem verdadeiras, então se a primeira for falsa, ele nem avalia a segunda).

```
void minusculaMaiuscula(char letra) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
        if (letra == letras[i]) { // só verifico o índice se a letra for igual
            if ((i < 5) || (10 <= i && i <= 30)) {
                printf("Maiúscula\n");
            } else {
                printf("Minúscula\n");
            }
            break; // se já encontrei a letra, não tem porque continuar procurando
        }
    }
}
```

Mas eu ainda acho esse *loop* desnecessário: não tem porque iterar pelas letras se dá para testar o valor da letra diretamente.

---

O mesmo vale para a outra função:

```
// sem o array
void vogalConsoante(char letra) {
    if (('a' <= letra && letra <= 'z') || ('A' <= letra && letra <= 'Z')) { // se não for letra, nem testo
        switch(letra) {
            case 'a':
            case 'e':
            case 'i':
            case 'o':
            case 'u':
            case 'A':
            case 'E':
            case 'I':
            case 'O':
            case 'U':
                printf("Vogal\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Consoante\n");
        }
    }
}

//--------------------------
// outra opção, sem o array
void vogalConsoante(char letra) {
    // se for maiúscula, converte para minúscula
    if ('A' <= letra && letra <= 'Z') {
        letra += 32;
    }
    if (('a' <= letra && letra <= 'z')) { // se não for letra, nem testo
        switch(letra) {
            case 'a':
            case 'e':
            case 'i':
            case 'o':
            case 'u':
                printf("Vogal\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Consoante\n");
        }
    }
}

//--------------------------
// com o array
void vogalConsoante(char letra) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
        if (letra == letras[i]) { // só verifico o índice se a letra for igual
            if (i < 10) {
                printf("Vogal\n");
            } else {
                printf("Consoante\n");
            }
            break; // se já encontrei a letra, não tem porque continuar procurando
        }
    }
}
```